# Zedgraph X-axis scaling values

Tags: c#, vb.net, zedgraph

I would like to increase the values shown in X-axis of a graph I am working on, in such a way:

X-axis starts in `0.125`, then it shows `0.250, 0.5, 1.0`, and then the numbers are `1.5, 2, 3,4,5,6,8,12` as in following image (of course the graph is incorrect, but I wanted to show the scaling of X-axis values)

[image]

Currently I have this:

[image]

to do this I have (vb.net version)

```
Imports System.Collections.Generic
Imports System.ComponentModel
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Drawing
Imports System.Text
Imports System.Windows.Forms
Imports ZedGraph

Namespace Grid
    Partial Public Class graficaControl
        Inherits Form
        Public Sub New()
            InitializeComponent()
            DrawGraph()
        End Sub


        Private Function h(ByVal x As Double) As Double
            If x = 0 Then
                Return 1
            End If

            Return Math.Sin(x) / x
        End Function

        Private Function f(ByVal x As Double) As Double
            If x = 0 Then
                Return 1
            End If

            Return Math.Sin(x)
        End Function

        Private Function g(ByVal x As Double) As Double
            If x = 1 Then
                Return 0
            End If

            Return Math.Cos(x)
        End Function



        Private Sub DrawGraph()
            Dim masterPane As ZedGraph.MasterPane = zedGraph.MasterPane
            Dim pane As New GraphPane()
            masterPane.PaneList.Clear()

            pane.XAxis.Title.Text = "X"
            pane.XAxis.Title.FontSpec.IsUnderline = False
            pane.XAxis.Title.FontSpec.IsBold = True
            pane.XAxis.Title.FontSpec.FontColor = Color.Blue
            pane.YAxis.Title.Text = "Y"
            pane.Title.Text = "Right - FF1"
            pane.Title.FontSpec.Fill.IsVisible = True
            pane.Title.FontSpec.IsBold = False

            'X AXIS UP
            pane.X2Axis.IsVisible = True
            pane.XAxis.IsVisible = False
            pane.YAxis.Scale.IsReverse = True

            'Grid
            pane.XAxis.MajorGrid.IsVisible = True
            pane.XAxis.MajorGrid.DashOn = 10
            pane.XAxis.MajorGrid.DashOff = 5
            pane.YAxis.MajorGrid.IsVisible = True
            pane.YAxis.MajorGrid.DashOn = 10
            pane.YAxis.MajorGrid.DashOff = 5
            pane.YAxis.MinorGrid.IsVisible = True
            pane.YAxis.MinorGrid.DashOn = 1
            pane.YAxis.MinorGrid.DashOff = 2
            pane.XAxis.MinorGrid.IsVisible = True
            pane.XAxis.MinorGrid.DashOn = 1
            pane.XAxis.MinorGrid.DashOff = 2


            'FOR TEXT
            pane.Legend.Position = LegendPos.Float
            pane.Legend.Location.CoordinateFrame = CoordType.ChartFraction
            pane.Legend.Location.AlignH = AlignH.Right
            pane.Legend.Location.AlignV = AlignV.Bottom
            pane.Legend.Location.TopLeft = New PointF(1.0F - 0.02F, 1.0F - 0.02F)



            iGraph(pane)

            ' Add to master 
            masterPane.Add(pane)

            'later add second graph
            Using g As Graphics = CreateGraphics()
                masterPane.SetLayout(g, PaneLayout.SquareColPreferred)
           End Using

            zedGraph.AxisChange()
            zedGraph.Invalidate()
        End Sub

        Private Sub iGraph(ByVal izq As GraphPane)
            izq.CurveList.Clear()
            Dim list As New PointPairList()
            Dim xmin As Double = -50
            Dim xmax As Double = 3
            Dim x As Double = xmin
            While x <= xmax
                list.Add(x, h(x))
                x += 0.01
            End While
            Dim myCurve As LineItem = izq.AddCurve("sen(x)/x", list, Color.ForestGreen, SymbolType.None)
        End Sub
        Private WithEvents zedGraph As ZedGraph.ZedGraphControl

        Private Sub InitializeComponent()            
        Me.zedGraph = New ZedGraph.ZedGraphControl()
        Me.SuspendLayout()
        '
        'zedGraph
        '
        Me.zedGraph.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill
        Me.zedGraph.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(0, 0)
        Me.zedGraph.Name = "Name"
        Me.zedGraph.ScrollGrace = 0.0R
        Me.zedGraph.ScrollMaxX = 0.0R
        Me.zedGraph.ScrollMaxY = 0.0R
        Me.zedGraph.ScrollMaxY2 = 0.0R
        Me.zedGraph.ScrollMinX = 0.0R
        Me.zedGraph.ScrollMinY = 0.0R
        Me.zedGraph.ScrollMinY2 = 0.0R
        Me.zedGraph.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(732, 461)
        Me.zedGraph.TabIndex = 1
        '
        'component
        '
        Me.AutoScaleDimensions = New System.Drawing.SizeF(6.0!, 13.0!)
        Me.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font
        Me.ClientSize = New System.Drawing.Size(732, 461)
        Me.Controls.Add(Me.zedGraph)
        Me.Name = "graph"
        Me.Text = "test" 
        Me.ResumeLayout(False)

    End Sub 
End Class
End Namespace
```

also c# version

```
using Microsoft.VisualBasic;
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using ZedGraph;

namespace Grid
{
    public partial class graficaControl : Form
    {
        public graficaControl()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            DrawGraph();
        }


        private double h(double x)
        {
            if (x == 0) {
                return 1;
            }

            return Math.Sin(x) / x;
        }

        private double f(double x)
        {
            if (x == 0) {
                return 1;
            }

            return Math.Sin(x);
        }

        private double g(double x)
        {
            if (x == 1) {
                return 0;
            }

            return Math.Cos(x);
        }



        private void DrawGraph()
        {
            ZedGraph.MasterPane masterPane = zedGraph.MasterPane;
            GraphPane pane = new GraphPane();
            masterPane.PaneList.Clear();

            pane.XAxis.Title.Text = "X";
            pane.XAxis.Title.FontSpec.IsUnderline = false;
            pane.XAxis.Title.FontSpec.IsBold = true;
            pane.XAxis.Title.FontSpec.FontColor = Color.Blue;
            pane.YAxis.Title.Text = "Y";
            pane.Title.Text = "Right - FF1";
            pane.Title.FontSpec.Fill.IsVisible = true;
            pane.Title.FontSpec.IsBold = false;

            //X AXIS UP
            pane.X2Axis.IsVisible = true;
            pane.XAxis.IsVisible = false;
            pane.YAxis.Scale.IsReverse = true;

            //Grid
            pane.XAxis.MajorGrid.IsVisible = true;
            pane.XAxis.MajorGrid.DashOn = 10;
            pane.XAxis.MajorGrid.DashOff = 5;
            pane.YAxis.MajorGrid.IsVisible = true;
            pane.YAxis.MajorGrid.DashOn = 10;
            pane.YAxis.MajorGrid.DashOff = 5;
            pane.YAxis.MinorGrid.IsVisible = true;
            pane.YAxis.MinorGrid.DashOn = 1;
            pane.YAxis.MinorGrid.DashOff = 2;
            pane.XAxis.MinorGrid.IsVisible = true;
            pane.XAxis.MinorGrid.DashOn = 1;
            pane.XAxis.MinorGrid.DashOff = 2;


            //FOR TEXT
            pane.Legend.Position = LegendPos.Float;
            pane.Legend.Location.CoordinateFrame = CoordType.ChartFraction;
            pane.Legend.Location.AlignH = AlignH.Right;
            pane.Legend.Location.AlignV = AlignV.Bottom;
            pane.Legend.Location.TopLeft = new PointF(1f - 0.02f, 1f - 0.02f);



            iGraph(pane);

            // Add to master 
            masterPane.Add(pane);

            //later add second graph
            using (Graphics g = CreateGraphics()) {
                masterPane.SetLayout(g, PaneLayout.SquareColPreferred);
            }

            zedGraph.AxisChange();
            zedGraph.Invalidate();
        }

        private void iGraph(GraphPane izq)
        {
            izq.CurveList.Clear();
            PointPairList list = new PointPairList();
            double xmin = -50;
            double xmax = 3;
            double x = xmin;
            while (x <= xmax) {
                list.Add(x, h(x));
                x += 0.01;
            }
            LineItem myCurve = izq.AddCurve("sen(x)/x", list, Color.ForestGreen, SymbolType.None);
        }
        private ZedGraph.ZedGraphControl zedGraph;

        private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            this.zedGraph = new ZedGraph.ZedGraphControl();
            this.SuspendLayout();
            //
            //zedGraph
            //
            this.zedGraph.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill;
            this.zedGraph.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0);
            this.zedGraph.Name = "Name";
            this.zedGraph.ScrollGrace = 0.0;
            this.zedGraph.ScrollMaxX = 0.0;
            this.zedGraph.ScrollMaxY = 0.0;
            this.zedGraph.ScrollMaxY2 = 0.0;
            this.zedGraph.ScrollMinX = 0.0;
            this.zedGraph.ScrollMinY = 0.0;
            this.zedGraph.ScrollMinY2 = 0.0;
            this.zedGraph.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(732, 461);
            this.zedGraph.TabIndex = 1;
            //
            //component
            //
            this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6f, 13f);
            this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
            this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(732, 461);
            this.Controls.Add(this.zedGraph);
            this.Name = "graph";
            this.Text = "test";
            this.ResumeLayout(false);

        }
    }
}
```

## Update

I have done the following and it is almost solved

```
    'disable old axis scale
    pane.X2Axis.Scale.IsVisible = False
    pane.X2Axis.MajorTic.IsAllTics = False

    ' new labels
    Dim x_vals = {0.125, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 1.0, 1.5, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 6.0, 8.0, 12.0, 16.0}

    ' create custom labels and custom grid-lines using LineObj
    For Each val As Double In x_vals

        'add line
        Dim line As New LineObj(pane.YAxis.Scale.Min, val, pane.YAxis.Scale.Max, val)
        line.Line.Style = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.DashStyle.Dash
        line.Line.Width = 1.0F
        pane.GraphObjList.Add(line)
        'add label
        Dim text As New TextObj(val.ToString(), pane.YAxis.Scale.Min, val)
        text.Location.AlignH = AlignH.Right
        text.FontSpec.Border.IsVisible = False
        text.FontSpec.Fill.IsVisible = False
        pane.GraphObjList.Add(text)
    Next
```

getting:

[image]

Comment: I do love ZedGraph questions! It is really a sad thing that the author decided to discontinue the project.

Comment: I think there are lots of programmers that still do use ZedGraph :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The scale you want is non-linear and so you need to change it to something like a logarithmic scale. Try screwing around with the [AxisType Enumeration](http://zedgraph.sourceforge.net/documentation/html/T_ZedGraph_AxisType.htm). At first glance I would guess you'll need a scaled logarithmic axis, or if that doesn't work just use an ordinal axis. It won't 'squeeze' the data points in but at least they will be labeled properly. If all else fails try using the string-array method (basically you fill out an array with the data points you want labeled).
Good luck!

EX:

```
pane.XAxis.Type = AxisType.Log;
```

Note that this will be a straight up base 10 logarithmic axis type, so it won't be the exact same numbers that you wanted.

Comment: how is it declared  pane.X2Axis.type.Log?

Comment: I included my best guess in my answer above. Hope this works! I don't have a chance to test this just now. Please report back and let us know how it goes...

Comment: [Here](http://zedgraph.dariowiz.com/index980a.html?title=Customize_the_scale_format) is another resource just in case the above doesn't suit your needs.

Comment: I followed your advices buthave other question though, please take a look at it, as you answered very well this issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15044886/zedgraph-magnitude-issue-in-x2axis-in-vb-net-or-c-sharp