# Zedgraph Magnitude issue in X2Axis in vb.net or c#

Tags: c#, vb.net, zedgraph

I am having hard time trying to do get the excel semi log plot with zedgraph:

[image]

I currently have:

[image]

To do this I have

```
Dim pane As New GraphPane()
'reverse order
pane.X2Axis.IsVisible = True
pane.XAxis.IsVisible = False
pane.YAxis.Scale.IsReverse = True
pane.YAxis.Scale.IsPreventLabelOverlap = True
' log type
pane.X2Axis.Type = AxisType.Log
pane.AxisChange()
' the y axis scale
pane.YAxis.Scale.Min = -20
pane.YAxis.Scale.Max = 120
'here I tried to manipulat x axis but had no success 

'the data

            Dim list As New PointPairList()
            Dim list2 As New PointPairList()        
            list.Add(0, 0)
            list.Add(125, 0)
            list.Add(250, 0)
            list.Add(500, 5)
            list.Add(750, 5)
            list.Add(1000, 10)
            list.Add(1500, 10)
            list.Add(2000, 5)
            list.Add(3000, 10)
            list.Add(4000, 10)
            list.Add(6000, 10)
            list.Add(8000, 20)
            list2.Add(125, 30)
            list2.Add(500, 30)
            list2.Add(750, 40)
            list2.Add(1000, 50)
            list2.Add(1500, 65)
            list2.Add(2000, 65)
            list2.Add(3000, 70)
            list2.Add(4000, 80)
            list2.Add(6000, 90)
            list2.Add(8000, 100)
            Dim myCurve As LineItem = pane.AddCurve("Series 1", list, Color.Blue, SymbolType.Diamond)
            Dim myCurve2 As LineItem = pane.AddCurve("Series 2", list2, Color.Magenta, SymbolType.Square)
```

As you can see, the data with **x2=125,250,500,750,1** is not similar TO EXCEL Semi Log plot as zedgraph's  numbers are really small Only in this part....

How to get the wanted excel graph with zedgraph?
Is there a way to zoom only that part or something?
Why is it appearing `10^-1,   10^0  ,10^1` ? and not  `10^2,  10^3  10^4`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set the axis minimum.

```
chart.GraphPane.YAxis.Scale.Min = 0;
chart.GraphPane.YAxis.Scale.Max = 100;
```

or something similar to this. Make sure you add the `GraphPane` part. I hope this works; again, I can't test it because I actually don't have this module installed on my current machine.

[This](http://sourceforge.net/projects/zedgraph/files/zedgraph%20documentation/5.1.0%20+%204.6.0/) is a pretty useful thing to get if you're using ZedGraph a lot. I was pointed at this by someone else here but I can't find their post to give them credit.